# MacBook Air doesn't power on with the power-on button

Tags: macbook-pro

MacBook Air doesn't power on with the power-on button. But when I remove battery connection and put back it works. As long as it is in sleep mode it works. But when I switch OFF it doesn't power on and needs the battery connection to be reconnected.

Comment: How long do you hold down the power button? It takes more than just a poke, like a normal keyboard key. Forgive me if you know this already.

Comment: Maybe the button is broken.

Comment: How do I know that the button is broken? externally it appears fine...

Answer (score 1):

### Have you tried resetting the **SMC** (System Management Controller)?

With charger plugged in, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd> on the left side of the keyboard, then press the <kbd>Power</kbd>.

> The LED on MagSafe power adapters might change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

> #### Indicators that your SMC might need to be reset
>
> - The computer fans run at high speed, though the computer is not experiencing heavy usage and is properly ventilated.
> - The keyboard backlight behaves incorrectly on Mac computers that have this feature.
> - The status indicator light (SIL) behaves incorrectly on Mac computers that have this feature.
> - Battery indicator lights, if present, behave incorrectly on Mac notebooks that have a non-removable battery.
> - The display backlight doesn't respond correctly to ambient light changes on Mac computers that have this feature.
> - The computer doesn't respond to the power button when pressed.
> - A Mac notebook computer doesn't respond properly when you close or open the lid.
> - The computer sleeps or shuts down unexpectedly.
> - The battery doesn't charge properly.
> - The MagSafe power adapter LED doesn't indicate the correct activity.
> - The computer is performing unusually slowly, though it isn't experiencing abnormally high CPU utilization.
> - Application icons may bounce in the Dock for an extended amount of time when opened.
> - Applications may not function correctly, or they may stop responding after being opened.
> - A computer that supports target display mode does not switch into or out of target display mode as expected, or it switches into or out of target display mode at unexpected times.
> - The illumination around the I/O ports on a Mac Pro (Late 2013) does not activate when you move the computer.

**Source:** https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201295

Comment: Yes I tried resetting the SMC. Did not work.

Comment: What are the specs of your MBA & Which model year? Many of the late '13 MBA had problems with the logic board.

Comment: It is 13 inch Macbook Air mid-2013, 1.7 GHz Intel Core i7 has 8 GB1600 MHz DDR3, Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB and 512 GB Hard disk.  OS X El Capitan. Thanks

Comment: When you reset the SMC, did the Magsafe LED change colors? If not, then the power button is physically broken to have not responded for the SMC reset. If color did change & still unresponsive to power on, its more than likely Logic Board.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.....The Magsafe LED color is orange when the laptop is partially charged and becomes green when it is fully charged (like normal). When I reset the SMC during that time it does not flicker nor does it change color change colors. If it is orange it remains orange and if it is green it remains green...Since past 5 days I have taken care not to use the power button to "Switch off" the Macbook.... I have kept it in the standby mode (by just closing the lid) ....Macbook works fine this way...Worried that if I "switch off" the Macbook with power button it wouldn't start again.